# HighStock pointRange issue

Tags: highcharts

I am having some difficulty getting pointRange to work for a HighStock combination chart I've written.

You can see the issue here, the bars should be 28 days wide but they are not. I can get this code to work on a non-HighStock chart but something is preventing it from working in HighStock and I've been unable to figure it out.

http://jsfiddle.net/3fnfy434/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            height: 450
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        rangeSelector : {
            inputEnabled: false,
            selected : 2,
                buttons: [{
                    type: 'month',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3m'
                }, {
                    type: 'year',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1y'
                }, {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All'
                }],
                labelStyle: {
                    color: '#40C6CE',
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
        },
        title : {
                text : 'test'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        yAxis: [{ 
            allowDecimals: false,
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return this.value;
                },
                style: {
                    color: '#25408F'
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 't',
                style: {
                    color: '#25408F'
                }
            }
        }],

        navigator: {
            baseSeries: 1
        },
        series : [{
            name: 's1',
            data:  d1,
            type: 'column',
            visible: true,
            pointRange: 28 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 0,
                valueSuffix: ''
            }
        },
        {
            name : 's2',
            data : d2,
            color: '#25408F',
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            },
            pointRange: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1,
                valueSuffix: ''
            }
        }]
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to set pointPadding / groupPadding as 0. http://jsfiddle.net/wpmzwt82/

Comment: This doesn't make any difference?

Comment: I should clarify that I mean the bars to be this wide, not just the space allocated to the point (I can see the width of the whole graph increasing but the bars remain the same.

Comment: Well, when I run the example: http://jsfiddle.net/wpmzwt82/ and resize the window, then bars width are updated. Which browser do you use?

Comment: That's really weird, I'm using Chrome 49.0.2623.110 and bars not being updated, no errors in the console either: http://s23.postimg.org/cmolm92nf/barwidth.png

Comment: @SebastianBochan I have been asked to revisit this by my client - are you able to take another look because I simply can't get the pointRange to work in this scenario. As you can see in the image above the bars are 1 day wide whereas I want them to be 28 days wide. Are you able to show me an image of your version working? cheers

Comment: Please set the ordinal xAxis parameter as false. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8fnfvtxy/2/